# double to certain string format

Tags: c#, .net

I have this simplified method:

```
private string GetStringValue(object Value)
{
    return ((double)Value).ToString();
}
```

which spews out:

1.8E-09

I intend to get this format though:

1.8e-009

Is this easily achievable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierExponent), I *think* you want:

```
// Separate variable just for clarity
double number = (double) Value;
return number.ToString("0.###e+000");
```

(Use `0.###E-000` if you only want the symbol for negative exponents.)

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of this but was not sure whether I can influence the E bit. By the way, please change E+000 -> e+000

Comment: Is it possible to suppress e for let us say anything with less than 4 numbers after the comma?

Comment: @csetzkorn: What comma? Do you mean the decimal point? If so, I don't *think* so, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use String.Format and use the right format string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

This should help with decimal format strings.

So

```
(double)Value.ToString("E")
```

would do it for en-US.

Answer (score 0):

```
return string.Format("{0:0.###E+000}", value);
```

Comment: Why would you explicitly call `string.Format` rather than just using `value.ToString` with a format specifier? The latter ends up being much simpler in my experience, when you only want to format a single value.

Comment: No, so you'd cast it to `double` first - which is cleaner anyway IMO as it shows in your code the type of value you're expecting. You could also cast to `IFormattable` if you really wanted.

Comment: that assumes the value is a double. if it's not you get a cast exception. In my instance a formatting exception should be thrown if the value is not a double. 6 or 1/2 dozen on possible runtime exceptions I guess.

Comment: If it's not a `double` and you were *expecting* a `double`, then an exception is absolutely the right result, IMO... and a casting exception shows the exact cause. If you just know you're expecting *some* kind of formattable value, then cast to `IFormattable` instead...

Comment: yeah, I can see how that makes sense and provides more value than a formatting exception.